# Perpendicular Distance from a Point to a line represented by two points

Tags: php, geometry, cartesian, cartesian-coordinates

I have a point C(Cx,Cy) and then a line represented by two points A(Ax,Ay) and B(Bx,By).
I need to find the perpendicular distance between the point C and the line represented by AB.
How do I do this in PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is straight forward.Its mathematics rather than PHP

```
<?php
    //Coordinates are (a,b) and (c,d)
    //the point (x,y) is the required point.
    $a=1;
    $b=2;
    $c=3;
    $d=4;

    $m=($d-$b)/($c-$a);
    //echo $m."\n";

    $x=10;
    $y=20;
    //echo $y-($m*$x)-$b+($m*$a)."\n";
    $distance=abs($y-($m*$x)-$b+($m*$a))/sqrt(1+($m*$m));
    echo $distance;
   ?>
```